# TFS2017 Code search configuration at TFS2017 Admin console

Tags: java-8

While configuring Search feature at TFS2017 admin console I am getting below error & configuration is getting failed. Although i have installed JDK 8.0 & server JRE8 update 20 & set the environment variable JAVA_HOME but still issue persists. Can someone help me out on this. Please suggest.

> "Search requires Oracle Server JRE 7 Update 55 or higher, or JRE 8
>   Update 20 or higher, and a suitable version was not detected or is not
>   correctly configured on this computer. You can download and install
>   the latest version by accepting the Oracle Binary Code License
>   Agreement for Server JRE and selecting ‘Configure’. Note that this
>   will set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the Java
>   installation directory, and that Server JRE does not provide automatic
>   updates. See Java installation notes for more information."

[Serach Config Wizard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CY7R.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Java installation notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/search/code/administration#software-dependencies) for Code Search configuration, make sure you have set the environment variable correctly.

***For example:*** as a variable name choose **JAVA_HOME** and as value set the path of the folder where JRE is installed, eg C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_11,

> If the Search configuration wizard does not detect a working
>   installation of Java Server JRE, it provides an option to download and
>   install the latest version. Internet connectivity is required to
>   download this from the Java website. If the target server does not
>   have Internet connectivity, you must download and install Server JRE
>   manually before attempting to install Code Search.
>
> During installation, the wizard sets the **JAVA_HOME** environment
>   variable to point to the Server JRE installation folder. The
>   configuration wizard may fail to detect an existing Server JRE
>   installation if it is not correctly configured, or if the
>   **JAVA_HOME** setting points to an earlier version than that required by Code Search.
>
> If there is a version of Server JRE **earlier** than the minimum
>   required by Code Search, and the JAVA_HOME variable is set to that
>   version, we recommend you install Search on a separate server because
>   changing the value of the **JAVA_HOME** variable may cause other
>   installed software to fail.
>
> If there is a version of Server JRE **equal to or later** than the
>   minimum required by Code Search, and it is not recognized by the
>   configuration wizard, you must set the value of the JAVA_HOME variable
>   to that version as described in the [Java troubleshooting guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/),
>   and then rerun the configuration wizard.

Comment: TFS java home is JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Search\Java\jre1.8.0_201'.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an intermittent issue for me. I had to get [Azul openJDK8](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=windows&package=jdk)
and JAVA_HOME in Environment variable set to

```
"C:...\zulu8.54.0.21-ca-jdk8.0.292-win_x64\zulu8.54.0.21-ca-jdk8.0.292-win_x64\"
```